# How to disable tab/indent lines in spacevim

Tags: neovim, spacevim

I recently decided to take the plunge to using nvim and decided to use the preconfigured space vim. I love it however I hate the tab/indent lines as seen below

[image]

I am reffering to the blue bars that preceed text.

I have tried the following to disable them but nothing has worked

In init.vim

```
let g:spacevim_buffer_index_type = 0
set listchars-=tab:\|\ 
let g:indentLine_enabled = 0
let g:spacevim_disabled_plugins = ['indentLine']
let g:spacevim_enable_guicolors = 0
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of change `init.vim`, you should use `SPC f v d` to open config file. and disable indent line in ui layer:

```
[[layers]]
  name = "ui"
  enable_indentline = false
```

and checkout this page for more info: https://spacevim.org/layers/ui/

Comment: Perfect that sorted it out. Thanks